# Lines with common words in outputs of 2 scripts

Tags: output, lines

I need to run two linux shell scripts and get lines from the second script that contain same words as lines in the output from the first (not the whole line is the same). For example:

```
Script #1 output:
Router 1: Ip address 10.0.0.1
Router 2: Ip address 10.0.1.1
Router 3: Ip address 10.0.2.1

Script #2 output:
Router 1: Model: Cisco 2960
Router 2: Model: Juniper MX960
Router 5: Model: Huwei S3300
```

So, finally I need a list of routers that are present in both outputs, but only lines from the second script, i.e. lines with model.

Comment: What tools/languages are available?

Comment: Please [edit] and describe *exactly* what you mean with *contain same words*. If the second output has a line saying "Router 2: Model: Ip Router" will that match?

Comment: Wolf, sorry, I was so concentrated on trying to explain what i need that forgot to mention that i mean linux shell scripts.

Comment: Jan Doggen. Yes, you are right, my example is not the best as model won't contain the word "Router" but rather some platform name like Huawei S3300. And router name would be some host name like loc-peer-1. Will correct the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the above two script output is stored/redirected to tmp1 and tmp2 respectively.

Below script will output the common `Router X` present in both the files.

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp1="$1"
tmp2="$2"
while read -r line
   do   
    routerName=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 1)
    if grep -q "$routerName" "$tmp2"
       then
        # Instead of printing you can add any logic
        echo $routerName
    fi
done < "$tmp1"
```

save the above script as filename.sh and pass the arguments

```
./filename.sh tmpScript1output_file tmpScript2output_file
```